# Caroufredsel fouc when cached

Tags: caroufredsel, fouc

We're experiencing a issue with the caroufredsel, where in the first time our site is open it load perfectly, but when it get cached and is opened again a F.O.U.C. occurs and the elements are briefly showed in vertical position.

The documentation tells that a "overflow: hidden" would resolve the problem (http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel#jumpNav-8), but in our case it don't.

Here is our code:

```
<div class="caroufredsel_wrapper" style="
    display: block; 
    text-align: start; 
    float: none; 
    position: relative; 
    top: auto; 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    left: auto; 
    z-index: auto; 
    width: 1170px; 
    height: 155px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    overflow: hidden;">

<div class="slider-politicas">
<div class="navegation-top"><span class="next">Next</span> <span class="prev">Prev</span></div>
<div class="block-content">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="block free-shipping">
<div class="block-title"><span>Free Shipping</span></div>
<div class="block-content">Free and fast Shipping.</div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="block secured-payment">
<div class="block-title"><span>Secure Payment</span></div>
<div class="block-content">Total payment protection.</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $sns_jq(document).ready(function() {
        $sns_jq('.slider-politicas .block-content ul').carouFredSel({
            responsive: true,
            width: '100%',
            scroll: {
                items: 1,
                duration: 800
            },
            items: {
                width: '290',
                visible: {
                    min: 4,
                    max: 10
                }
            },
            next: '.slider-politicas  .prev',
            prev: '.slider-politicas .next',
            auto: true
        });
    });
// ]]></script>
</div>
```

Here is our develop website: http://www.comercialbv.com/

Comment: have you found a solution to this? i'm on the same situation.